# SQL Query With Max Value from Child Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

Three pertinent tables: tracks (music tracks), users, and follows.

The follows table is a many to many relationship relating users (followers) to users (followees).

I'm looking for this as a final result:
`<track_id>`, `<user_id>`, `<most popular followee>`

The first two columns are simple and result from a relationship between tracks and users. The third is my problem. I can join with the follows table and get *all* of the followees that each user follows, but how to get *only* the most followee that has the highest number of follows.

Here are the tables with their pertinent columns:

```
tracks: id, user_id (fk to users.id), song_title
users: id
follows: followee_id (fk to users.id), follower_id (fk to users.id)
```

Here's some sample data:

```
TRACKS
1, 1, Some song title

USERS
1
2
3
4

FOLLOWS
2, 1
3, 1
4, 1 
3, 4
4, 2
4, 3

DESIRED RESULT
1, 1, 4
```

For the desired result, the 3rd field is 4 because as you can see in the FOLLOWS table, user 4 has the most number of followers.

I and a few great minds around me are still scratching our heads.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I threw this into Linqpad because I'm better with Linq.

```
Tracks
    .Where(t => t.TrackId == 1)
    .Select(t => new { 
        TrackId = t.TrackId,
        UserId = t.UserId, 
        MostPopularFolloweeId = Followers
            .GroupBy(f => f.FolloweeId)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .Key
    });
```

The resulting SQL query was the following (@p0 being the track id):

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[TrackId], [t0].[UserId], (
    SELECT [t3].[FolloweeId]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t2].[FolloweeId]
        FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t1].[FolloweeId]
            FROM [Followers] AS [t1]
            GROUP BY [t1].[FolloweeId]
            ) AS [t2]
        ORDER BY [t2].[value] DESC
        ) AS [t3]
    ) AS [MostPopularFolloweeId]
FROM [Tracks] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[TrackId] = @p0
```

That outputs the expected response, and should be a start to a cleaner query.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an aggregation query with `row_number()`.  I'm a little confused on how all the joins come together:

```
select t.*
from (select t.id, f.followee_id, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by t.id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from followers f join
           tracks t 
           on f.follow_id = t.user_id
      group by t.id, f.followee_id
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: we'll give this a try

Comment: This didn't give us what we were hoping and I didn't/don't have time to figure out why. Thanks for the answer!